# Почему не работает страницы в wordpress кроме главной?

Tags: wordpress

Никак не могу разобратся с проблемой перехода по ссылкам меню, работает только главная страница при попытке перехода на другую страницу выдает ошибку что страница не найдена

> The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the
>   referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author
>   of that page about the error.

Переход по меню работал при использования в Permalink "Custom structure:/index.php/%postname%/" но тогда в ссылках на всех страница показывает "index.php". Используя любую другую стурктуры пермалинков страница так же не найдена.
Использую xampp server.

В файл httpd.conf в нес следующие изменения

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Так выглядит .htaccess файл

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Wordpress%20Projects/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /Wordpress%20Projects/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

В каждом файле php для страниц прописано имя шаблона

```
/*
    Template Name: Home
*/
```

В разделе "Pages" для каждой страници задан шаблон.

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с данной проблемой

Comment: Если вместо `/Wordpress%20Projects/index.php` оставить только `index.php`?

Comment: все так же страница не найдена

Comment: И `RewriteBase /Wordpress%20Projects/` за комментировать.

Comment: никаких изменений, RewriteRule index.php [L] - так нужно было? или со слэшом и точкой? хотя вроде и так и так никакой разнице не вижу

Comment: Что за ересь в хтацессе в блоке ВП... '/Wordpress%20Projects/index.php` '/Wordpress%20Projects/' . Удали это нафик. А если нужно обработать эти урлы - вынеси их отдельно и обработай как надо. По сабжу см https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9E/%D0%9D%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: это сам wordpress сгенерировал я уже уберал но это не помогло и почемуто в урл путь всеравно стоит с Wordpress%20Projects/

Comment: майнгот... Надо было писать сразу, что это на винде в каком-то недосервере. Да ещё и ВП в *подкаталоге  с пробелом*.
Короче, создай на этом недосервере виртуалхост (в каталоге БЕЗ пробелов и в нижнем регистре) и работай с ним.

Comment: Огромное тебе спасибо это решило мою проблему и головную боль! Запости как ответ, что бы я отметил это решением.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в локальном сервере на винде, размещении в подкаталоге и пробелах в путях.

Для локальных серверов стоит создавать virtualhost и работать уже с ним.
В наименовании каталогов не использовать пробелы, русские символы и верхний регистр.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, дело тут в htaccess, сталкивался с похожими симптомами. Однако, если все же нет. то попробуйте проверить в базе таблицу с настройками Wordpress. Там есть поле, отвечающее за url сайта, возможно, стоит неправильно.

Comment: урл стоит http://localhost/Wordpress%20Projects/